# Display the backtrace of a method call from the repl?

Tags: ruby, pry

Is there such a tool (maybe pry plugin?) that would print the backtrace of a given method call without having to insert anything on the source code?

Something like

```
repl> show-backtrace Cat.new.sleep(5)
# >... Cat.sleep
# >... Cat#initialize
# >...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [TracePoint](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/TracePoint.html#method-i-enable) class for it.

```
trace = TracePoint.new(:call) do |tp|
    p [tp.lineno, tp.defined_class, tp.method_id, tp.event]
end

trace.enable

class Cat
  def initialize
    # code
  end
  def sleep(arg)
    arg
  end
end

Cat.new.sleep(5)

# >> [8, Cat, :initialize, :call]
# >> [11, Cat, :sleep, :call]
```

Read the available [Events](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/TracePoint.html#class-TracePoint-label-Events).

`:call` - call a Ruby method.

[Ruby has introduced the `TracePoint` API](http://kgrz.io/2014/04/19/ruby-trace-leave-oh-my.html) with the release of Ruby 2.0. Earlier, there was a similar tool that let you track operations in any Ruby program called `set_trace_func`. However, using it was really slow and ugly. This new `TracePoint` API aims to replace it.